# How to serialize Firebase object into json using code generation in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to follow the steps in this flutter doc, https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json to make fireauth user object into json through code generation. Here is my code:

```html
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'google_signIn_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class GoogleSignInResponse {
  final User user;

  GoogleSignInResponse(this.user);

  factory GoogleSignInResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GoogleSignInResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$GoogleSignInResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Here is the package I am using to do code generation:

```
 build_runner: ^1.11.5
 json_serializable: ^3.5.1
 json_annotation: ^3.1.1
```

The documentation didn't say how to do it when an custom object contains a third party package object. Can anyone help me with this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: seems like you have'nt read entire page yet, you have all you need to know about code generation further down on that page https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries

Comment: I do know how to do code generation but I don't know how to serialize the 3rd party package object like fireauth.user into json.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define how to serialize the User object using [explicitToJson](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/explicitToJson.html)? When set to ´true´, generated ´toJson´ methods will explicitly call `toJson` on nested objects.

Did you run the build_runner itself?

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

On top of that, I would recommend also using the [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed). While Freezed will not generate your typical fromJson/toJson by itself, it knowns what [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) is. Making a class compatible with json_serializable is very straightforward:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'model.freezed.dart';
part 'model.g.dart';

@freezed
class Model with _$Model {
  factory Model.first(String a) = First;
  factory Model.second(int b, bool c) = Second;

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ModelFromJson(json);
}
```

In your class, only define the `fromJson` method. The `toJson` will also be generated.

On top of JSON serialization, you will also get immutability (which is crucial for [State Management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)), [Union/Sealed classes](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes), [copyWith](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#copywith) method and object value == operator, and a few other gems.

Comment: I did run build_runner but I didn't do the explicitToJson thingy. I am not sure what that does but I will do more research on it!
Also, what is the difference of suing freeze package? What is the benefit of doing that versus using the the normal json_serialzable?

Comment: On top of JSON serialization, you will also get immutability (which is crucial for [State Management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)), [Union/Sealed classes](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes), [copyWith](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#copywith) method and object value == operator, and a few other gems. (End of my answer)